# Multiple equals cells, then chek offset cells

Tags: vba, excel

I want to check all ID's in a B column (PIB) and if there a duplicates ID's to check A column (REGION), if those PIB's have multiple regions. I want to check if regions for the PIB's which are duplicates, have a unique or let's say different REGION. [image]

I stucked with marking B column and duplicates with following code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range, cell As Range, i As Integer

Set rng = Range("A2:D400")
Set rng2 = Range("B2:B400")
Set rng3 = Range("A2:A400")

For Each cell In rng
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng2, cell) > 1 Then
        cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 26
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

From this code, I've tried to add some nested IF, but then is nothing happens:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range, cell As Range, i As Integer

Set rng = Range("A2:D400")
Set rng2 = Range("B2:B400")
Set rng3 = Range("A2:A400")

For Each cell In rng
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng2, cell) > 1 Then
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng3, cell) > 1 Then
        cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 26
    End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think I understand what your trying to do, but what isn't working? I also thing the line For Each cell In rng should be rng2?

Comment: @jcarroll, I think that is the same..rng is wider range than rng2..

Comment: It isn't the same at all, your saying loop through column A:D vs loop through column B

Comment: A simple solution to your problem, with no VBA would be to combine the region and PIB, then just check for duplicates.

Comment: Would a conditional formatting formula not work?

Comment: I can put conditional formula for B column, but I wonder how will I do it for a A column? COUNTIF?

Comment: The question is, what do you want to do with the duplicate `Region | PIB` combinations? You can get only so far with CF.

Comment: I want to copy those rows for example in a new Sheet. As you can see on the image - I want those 3 rows to copy with PIB 100003734 in other sheet.

Comment: why those 3 specific rows? it doesn't make sense to me? You have region 1 listed once and region 2 listed twice? What about the other region 2 above it (for the same number)? Do you really want to just copy 1 instance of each unique region?

Comment: You are right, I missed it one above and one below row. Maybe just to copy only ONE PIB where is for ots duplicates has multiple regions. In a new sheet I would copy just 100003734 and thats it. Thanks for your engagement!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-VBA solution (since it seems you are OK with it).

1. C1 = `Check`, E1 = 'Check', E2 = `>0`
2. C2 = `=IF(COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,A:A,"<>"&A2)>0,1,0)`, then drag down

[image]

3. Advanced Filter as shown here:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately,  your function is not working for me. I have 1 on C column for PIB id which occurred only once.. maybe vba code is easier to control?